# Why does `copy-of()` not allow this XSL to be streamable ("burst-mode")?

Tags: xslt-3.0

I'm trying to convert a lot of XSL transforms to XSLT 3.0 so that I can take advantage of streaming, since a lot of the XML I'm dealing with is quite large. I'm running into a problem with this relatively simple transform. I'm given to understand that `copy-of()` should allow multiple consuming operands, but Saxon is still complaining about it.

When I try to apply this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ROOT>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/ROOT/ROW/copy-of(.)" />
        </ROOT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <xsl:if test="contains(WD_BATCH_ID, 'timeoff_corr')" >
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...to XML that looks like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <ROW>
        <INT_ID>229274</INT_ID>
        <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff20200105_5365_78659138_TEST</WD_BATCH_ID>
        <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>229174</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
        <DATE_WORKED>2019-12-31</DATE_WORKED>
        <EMPLOYEE_ID>103839</EMPLOYEE_ID>
        <WEEK_END_DATE>2020-01-05</WEEK_END_DATE>
        <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2020-01-05</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
        <HOURS>2</HOURS>
        <PAY_COMPONENT>INVALID_TIMEOFF1</PAY_COMPONENT>
        <TK_COMMENTS>kns_timeoff20200105_5365_78659138</TK_COMMENTS>
        <SS_REQUEST_ID>78658686</SS_REQUEST_ID>
        <REQUEST_ID>78659138</REQUEST_ID>
        <PROCESS_DATE>2020-02-10</PROCESS_DATE>
        <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
    <INT_ID>1008269</INT_ID>
    <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_wd20200105_26285_78659138_TEST</WD_BATCH_ID>
    <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>WK2.1008269</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
    <DATE_WORKED>2020-01-05</DATE_WORKED>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>101113</EMPLOYEE_ID>
    <WEEK_END_DATE>2020-01-05</WEEK_END_DATE>
    <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2020-01-05</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
    <HOURS>40</HOURS>
    <PAY_COMPONENT>INVALID_CODE1</PAY_COMPONENT>
    <TK_COMMENTS>kns_wd20200105_26285_78659138</TK_COMMENTS>
    <SS_REQUEST_ID>78658686</SS_REQUEST_ID>
    <REQUEST_ID>78659138</REQUEST_ID>
    <PROCESS_DATE>2020-02-10</PROCESS_DATE>
    <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
</ROW>
    <ROW>
    <INT_ID>234387</INT_ID>
    <WD_BATCH_ID>kns_timeoff_corr_test_7_78668139</WD_BATCH_ID>
    <WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>234386</WD_PAY_INPUT_ID>
    <DATE_WORKED>2019-12-12</DATE_WORKED>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>150389</EMPLOYEE_ID>
    <WEEK_END_DATE>2019-12-15</WEEK_END_DATE>
    <EFFECTIVE_DATE>2020-01-05</EFFECTIVE_DATE>
    <HOURS>-9</HOURS>
    <PAY_COMPONENT>Jury Duty</PAY_COMPONENT>
    <TK_COMMENTS>kns_wd20200105_7_78668139</TK_COMMENTS>
    <SS_REQUEST_ID>78668068</SS_REQUEST_ID>
    <REQUEST_ID>78668139</REQUEST_ID>
    <PROCESS_DATE>2020-02-19</PROCESS_DATE>
    <PROCESS_STATUS>C</PROCESS_STATUS>
</ROW>
</ROOT>
```

...it should produce identical XML, but omitting any `ROW` nodes wherein the `WD_BATCH_ID` child doesn't contain `timeoff_corr`. This works as expected without streaming declared, but with streamable declared "yes", Saxon complains `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Template rule is declared streamable but it does not satisfy the streamability rules. * There is more than one consuming operand: {contains(...)} on line 17, and {xsl:copy-of} on line 18`

Sure enough, there is a `contains()` on 17 and a `xsl:copy-of` on 18, but [according to Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/burst-mode-streaming.html) using `select="/ROOT/ROW/copy-of(.)"` should allow "non-streamy" operations on the copy of that node.

What am I missing, that's preventing this XSL from being streamable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different mode for that template where that different mode does not require streaming, then your code will work.

The streamability analysis for your current template, if you have declared the mode as streamable, will not cover your code path and detect that you just want to use the template for grounded nodes, it simply checks whether a forwards only, one consuming operand execution for a particular template would be possible.

I think you could also simply use `<xsl:copy-of select="/ROOT/ROW/copy-of()[contains(WD_BATCH_ID, 'timeoff_corr')]" />` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="/ROOT/ROW/copy-of(.)" />`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't had a chance to test this, yet. Optimization has taken a back-seat to effectiveness, apparently.